# Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined (TypeError)

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native, mobile-application

I am developing a mobile app using React Native with TypeScript. I am using the FontAwesome Library for icons, but I am encountering an error. Here is my code:

Icon Component:

```
import React from "react";
import Icon from "react-native-fontawesome-pro";
import { IconType } from "../Functions/IconsType";
import { IconTypes } from "../Numrations/Numration";

type Props = {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  type: IconTypes;
  size: number;
};
function IconForm(props: Props) {
  const { name, color, type, size } = { ...props };
  return <Icon name={name} color={color} type={IconType(type)} size={size} />;
}
export default IconForm;
```

And here is my file:

```
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Colors from "../../Colors/Colors";
import IconForm from "../../Icons/IconFrom";
import { IconTypes } from "../../Numrations/Numration";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import TextLabel from "../Texts/TextLabel";
import Lexicons from "../../Lexicons/Lexicons";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

function SelectLevelHeader() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainView}>
      <View style={styles.viewIcon}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={[Colors.iconBackgroundYellow, Colors.darkorange]}
          style={[styles.icon, styles.shadowProp]}
          start={{ x: 0.0, y: 0.25 }}
          end={{ x: 0.5, y: 1.0 }}
        >
          <IconForm
            name="music"
            color={Colors.black}
            size={30}
            type={IconTypes.Solid}
          />
        </LinearGradient>
       
      </View>
      <TextLabel title={Lexicons.games} textStyle={styles.text} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default SelectLevelHeader;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: 7,
    height: 90,
    backgroundColor: Colors.darkorange,
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  icon: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    borderRadius: 25,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  shadowProp: {
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    marginBottom: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    shadowRadius: 10,
  },
  viewIcon: {
    width: "45%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignContent: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  text: {
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    height: 50,
    padding: 15,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 22,
  },
});
```

Can you provide more information about the error you are encountering so that I can help you resolve the problem?

Comment: The project react-native-fontawesome-pro hasn't been updated for 4 years. Maybe checkout https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-native-fontawesome

Comment: I cant seem to see the error. Can you share the error you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue which was that I forgot to add these lines in the App.tsx

```
import { configureFontAwesomePro } from "react-native-fontawesome-pro";
configureFontAwesomePro();
```

after adding this my app is running and the icon works.